# Running a single Karma Jasmine test in Web Storm via Right Click Menu

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, webstorm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have setup `Idea Web Storm` and can run `Karma` Tests successfully if the test specs are defined in the `karam.conf.js`.

However, if I right click on the JS file and choose 'Run MySpec.js', I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/node MyTestSpec.js

/Users/dev/WebstormProjects/demow/test/MyTestSpec.js:4
describe('Activate wallet controller --', function () {
^
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/WebstormProjects/demow/test/MyTestSpec.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Maybe it's not possible to run JS tests in this way.

Here is the config in `WebStorm`:
[image]

The KT config linked to the karma.conf.js file works OK as I mentioned.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a node debug configuration instead of a karma configuration ?

Comment: So, there is absolutely no way to run just one test like (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10067)? If I'm debugging one test, I want to run just that test, not the whole suite. I would assume this is a very common workflow?

Comment: @David That's the purpose of [focused test](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/focused_specs.html), that's good enough as far as I am concerned...

Answer (score 12):

I don't have a WebStorm-specifc solution for you - However, if you want to simply be able to only run certain jasmine tests instead of all of them, this is possible through use of "[focused specs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/focused_specs.html)"

Essentially, If you change `describe` to `fdescribe` or `it` to `fit`, jasmine will only run the specs with the `f` prefix and ignore all others.

Here's an example:

```
fdescribe('Spec1', function () {

    it('should do something', function () {
        ...
    });
});

describe('Spec2', function () {

    it('should do something', function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

If you run jasmine tests on this file, all `it`s in the `Spec1` `fdescribe` block will be run.

So if you can get WebStorm to run *all* your specs, you can use `fdescribe` and `fit` to focus the run on only specific ones.

Just be careful not to commit your code with `fit` and `fdescribe` still in it, or you might inadvertently cause your CI server to skip running most of your specs :)

Comment: I added the bounty a week ago, this is exactly what I ended up using after more research.

Comment: there's also the karma `ddescribe`, for anyone interested

Comment: I find it rather silly needing to poke the code rather than having just a `--grep` option all along... Is there really no other way but to tinker with the tests and making sure not to `git add .`?

Comment: I agree with @IngwiePhoenix - I really don't like the idea of having to tweak the code. You warn about not committing 'fit' and 'fdescribe' but it's just so easy to miss when making lots of other code changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run karma tests this way - the required modules are not loaded. What are you trying to do - running individual test file? There is no way to pass a spec file to karma directly - see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/553

If you like to use Node.js run configuration to run karma tests, the correct parameters would be the following:

- Javascript file: /usr/local/bin/karma
- application parameters: start karma.conf.js

Comment: Agreed this seems impossible.  Running them via whats configured in the karma.conf.js works well.  Would be nice just to run a single suite quickly without have to edit the karma.conf.js file.

Answer (score 0):

For an angular2 project, copy karma.conf.js and src/test.ts files to files called them something like karma.single.conf.js and src/test.single.ts.

Edit the karma.single.conf. Change the 2 places that reference src/test.ts to src/test.single.ts (files and pattens).

In the test.single.ts file change

```
let context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
```

to the regex for the test file or files you want to test

```
 let context = require.context('./', true, /data\.service\.spec\.ts/);
```

Then run->Edit Configurations create a Karma target and change the configuration file to karma.single.conf.js